# Как в цикле Django найти остаток от деления?

Tags: python, django

Хочу сделать что-то вроде этого, но так в Django нельзя

```
{% for i in list %}
{% if i.pk%2 ==0 %}
HI
{% else %}
BYE
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8494209

Answer (score 0):

Для вашей задачи достаточно проверить, делится ли значение на 2 нацело. В Django template для такой задачи следует использовать встроенный тег **divisibleby**, который возвращает True, если значение делится на аргумент без остатка.

Необходимая вам реализация будет следующей:

```
{% for i in list %}
{% if i.pk|divisibleby:2 %}
HI
{% else %}
BYE
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

> [Ссылка на документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#s-divisibleby)